# Radio buttons are slow to change with Angular debounce enabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, radio-button

When I turn on debounce, the radio buttons are really slow to switch. For a half second I see both buttons enabled, and then the old one clears.  It works ok, but visually it is annoying.

**Note:** I found the answer, I'm just posting this for others to learn.

Here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="formExample">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <form novalidate ng-model-options="{ debounce: { default: 500 } }">
          <input type="radio" ng-model="formdata.t1" value="yes" />
          <input type="radio" ng-model="formdata.t1" value="no" />
          <input type="radio" ng-model="formdata.t1" value="na" />
      <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset" />
      <input type="submit" ng-click="update(formdata)" value="Save" />
    </form>
    <pre>form = {{formdata | json}}</pre>
    <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
    <script>
      angular.module('formExample', [])
        .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.master = {};

          $scope.update = function(formdata) {
            $scope.master = angular.copy(formdata);
          };

          $scope.reset = function() {
            $scope.formdata = angular.copy($scope.master);
          };

          $scope.reset();
        }]);
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I forgot to put a **name** attribute on the radio button set. This fixes the problem.

```
          <input type="radio" ng-model="formdata.t1" name="t1" value="yes" />
          <input type="radio" ng-model="formdata.t1" name="t1" value="no" />
          <input type="radio" ng-model="formdata.t1" name="t1" value="na" />
```

Also validation would have been screwed up without a name (if I remove the form novalidate).